# Arbitrary $n \rightarrow n$ or $n+1$can be written as sum of different primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the following task:

Let us have an $n$ positive integer. Prove, that $n$ or $n+1$(can be both of them) can be written down as the sum of different primes.

What I tried:

I think Chebysev's Theorem could help, since it says that in the interval $[n,2n]$, we can always find a prime number.

Let us have first the $n$ number. We know that in the interval $[\frac{n}{2} , n]$ we can always find a prime, let's say this prime is $p_1$. Next we use that we can find a prime in $[\frac{n}{4}, \frac{n}{2}]$, this prime should be $p_2$, and so on, we do the same for $n+1$. I just have no idea what prime we should choose, and why will be the sum $n$ or $n+1$.

Edit: It is maybe unclear, it is forbidden to use a prime more than once, so you can't write $4= 2+2$ but if $n$ is prime, you can write $n=n$.

Is my idea related to the question, or is there a more elegant version? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is wrong for $n=1$ or $n=2$

Comment: $n+1=2$ can be written as $2$ :)

Comment: If $n=2$, both $2$ and $3$ are good $\rightarrow 2 = 2, 3=3$.

Comment: 2 is **not** a sum of different primes (as would be 3)

Comment: The task name is strange then, the task is that you can always write either $n$ or $n+1$ as the sum of different prime means, that you can't use the same prime twice or more.

Comment: Let's say, for $n=3$, $4$is bad, because you can only write $2+2$, which is forbidden, but $3$ is good, since $3=3$.

Comment: I edited the task, check it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you are definitely on the right track.

As you note in your comment, the result is true for $n=1$.  Proceed by strong induction assuming that the result is true for $n=1, 2,\dots, k$.

Then use your idea with Chebyshev's Theorem to show that the result is true for $n=k+1$.

Comment: Here is my thought about the induction: For $n=1$ it is true, since we can write $2=2$. Suppose, that the result is true for $k$, and we show that for $n = k+1$, it is true aswell. If it is true for $k$, then either $k$ or $k+1$ can be written down in this form. If $k+1$ is the correct one, I am done for $k+1$. If I can write down $k$, but not $k+1$, I need to show that $k+2$ can be written down too. I am stuck here, I thought about twin primes, or what is the thought here? :)

Comment: I thought, that if we use Ind Hyp. we know that $k = p_1+p_2...$, so we know, that $k+2=2+p_1+p_2...$. If we didn't use $2$ for any $p_i$, we are done, else we just add $2$ to a $p_i$ and we need, that $p_i + 2$ must be a prime, so we need to use the first one from a twin prime pair?

Comment: I am using this version of Chebyshev: For $w>1$ there is prime $p$ with $w<p<2w$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).  If $n=k+1$ is even, then we find a prime $p$ with $\frac{n}{2}<p<n$.  Then the remaining piece is $n-p$ and $0<n-p<\frac{n}{2}$.  Since $n-p<\frac{n}{2}<p$, we have that $n-p$ is at least $2$ less than $p$, so by the induction hypothesis we can write $n-p$ or $n-p+1$ as a sum of primes and this case holds.  In the case of $n=k+1$ being odd, we find a prime $p$ with $\frac{n+1}{2}<p<1$, and proceed similarly.  (It works out again.)

Answer (score 1):

Proceed by induction. Suppose $p$ is the largest prime less than or equal to $n$. From Chebysev's Theorem, $p>n/2$, so $n-p<p$. From our assumptions, $n-p$ or $n-p+1$ can be expressed as a sum of distinct primes (all less than $p$), so either $n=p+(n-p)$ or $n+1=p+(n-p+1)$ can be expressed as a sum of distinct primes.

Comment: Wow, is this already a complete situation? :)

Comment: Missed the case when $n-p+1$ is actually p ._.